# How do I convert lower case text to uppercase text in Microsoft Word?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-word, typing

I want to convert lower case text to uppercase text in Microsoft Word.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Microsoft Office 2007 you can use the *Change Case* button on the *Home* tab.

[image: Change case button]

If that is not what you are looking for you will need to add more details to your question.

Comment: Or press Shift+F3.

Comment: @Johannes Rössel Shift+F3 is a nice quick way to cycle through the casing options.

Comment: Very odd having a button that changes the text mixed up with formating that just changes the look of the text.

Answer (score 17):

When you've had caps lock on by mistake, highlight the words you typed and press Shift+F3.  Pressing Shift+F3 repeatedly swaps between upper case, title case and lower case.

eg. if you type:

```
tHIS IS A TEST.
```

... then select all the text and press Shift+F3:

```
This IS A TEST.
```

... then press Shift+F3 again:

```
THIS IS A TEST.
```

... and Shift+F3 again:

```
this is a test.
```

... and Shift+F3 one last time:

```
This is a test.
```

It's interesting that the behaviour is a little different if there is no full stop (period character) in the selected text.  Shift+F3 then capitalizes every word when switching to title case:

```
This Is A Test
```

Hope this helps.

Matthew

Comment: As for the funny difference with the trailing dot: when applying styles in Word, Word is also aware of *what* is selected. Things like bold and italic are preserved if less than 50% of the text is formatted in bold or italic. If 50% or more uses that formatting, then applying a new paragraph style removes that character formatting on the fly... (Nice answer; welcome at Super User!)

Comment: Pressing Shift+F3 toggles between capitalizing all the letters in the selected text and capitalizing only the first letter of each word. This happens whether the sentence ends in a full stop/period or not. [At least this is what I experienced when I tried it myself.]

Comment: Arjan, that's a funny thing about bold or italic, I hadn't noticed that!  Thanks for your warm welcome, I've only been here a couple days so far.

Comment: Is there a mac version? function/shift/command f3 all don't work.

Answer (score 6):

Hold Shift when typing?

Comment: And it even works on websites...

Comment: To the downvoter, this answer was written before the edit was done. Look at the revision history and get a sense of humor :)

Comment: Cool answer, I did this way back when

Answer (score 2):

Shift+F3 does not work for some strings, like

> 95ad861b134e39cbd7ecd6c9070a58f4

If you highlight that then hit Shift+F3, nothing happens.  You have to either use the *Change Case* button as shown above or add an extra word, like

> 95ad861b134e39cbd7ecd6c9070a58f4 test

Then Shift+F3 will cycle through the capitalization options.

If you have a few minutes, write "3D" into Word, highlight it, then hit Shift+F3 a few times.  Why do you think this feature was implemented in this manner?

Comment: The only thing I know about 3D for the [quoted printable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable) characters is the =3D is the encoded form of '=', i.e. similar to `&amp;`. But for those of us without Word could you let us know what it does do?

Comment: Shift F3 simply change “3D” to “3d”. Nothing funny happens. I’m using Office 2013.

Comment: @FranklinYu I'm sorry I should have been clearer.  I found it weird that it would go from 3D to 3d but never 3d to 3D

Comment: Ok, that is indeed unexpected. Probably just a bug though. Not just `3D`, but any single word starting with a number, like `42deadbeef`.

Answer (score 1):

If you highlight that then hit Shift+F3, nothing happens. You have to either use the Change

Case button as shown above or add an extra word, like

Ctrl + Shift + A